# How i can Adjust icons on top left

Tags: html, css

Hello guy's i have small problem in this design,
this is in my laptop , i want all to looks like that:
[image]

[the icons must be in top left not in the center this is in tablet
this is the problem:
[image]

also this in i need to appear in left:
[image]

i need the 2nd and 3rd pictures to look like the first one and thank you .

the code not allow me to put it here 
so i can send it to you to see .
my regards friends

[the icons is out of the box !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX7Vi.jpg)

[the blue line need to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co6Hp.png)

Comment: Use `position:absolute` to set in top left

Comment: I have created a sample, Is this is the output you are expecting https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/6mo4q0xn/6/

Comment: Hey guy's i can't do it ,this is the code
https://jsfiddle.net/medhman/kx2f1paj/1/

Comment: You can use table format.

Comment: table format like what my friend , can you give me an example ? or you can see the the code above !

Comment: Just add `width:100%` to `.mostPopular li a`

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: In this project you can't use Flexbox?

Comment: @Rob i copied the link just for picture to appear not to get traffic my friend .

Comment: @Roy My friend i try it , but the icons becomes out of the box my friend ! any other way ! thank you

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I said. Read the link.

Comment: @Rob my friend it's not allow me to add code here that's why ! btw i delete my site link from the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you pls try this. i add parent div for max width and icon position changed

**css**

```
    .panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #F7FAFE;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}
.panel-default {
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #ddd;
}


.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.mostPopular {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mostPopular .headText h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 275px;
    color: #27ae60;
}
.headText {
        text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.headText h2 {
    color: #27ae60;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.mostPopular #pop {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.mostPopular p {
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, 'Helvetica Condensed Bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #929292;
    color: #768696;
    padding: 12px 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mostPopular li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 7px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.mostPopular li .index {
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.mostPopular li a {
    text-align: left;
    color: #505d69;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, 'Helvetica Condensed Bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mostPopular li .count {
    width: 40px;
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.headLine {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #83b755, 0 -2px 0 #4b8424;
    background: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #3c81de;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mostPopular #pop {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

.mostPopular li .index {
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.thumbnaidl {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27ae60;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    margin-top: -25.7px;
    padding: 2px;
    flex-direction: row;
    height:23px;

}
.t11img {
    width: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    display: flex;
}
```